# Appending data to load functions?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

Is there a way that I can append additional information to my load functions?

For example,  I want to make it so that a timestamp automatically accompanies my load functions without having to specify it inside each load function? It seems like hooks could do something like this, but I can't figure out how exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You can just return it from the [load function of your root layout](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#layout-data). The data will be merged with the page data. Just make sure the property name is unique enough to not be overwritten accidentally by some page data timestamp.

> If multiple `load` functions return data with the same key, the last one 'wins' — the result of a layout `load` returning `{ a: 1, b: 2 }` and a page load returning `{ b: 3, c: 4 }` would be `{ a: 1, b: 3, c: 4 }`.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. If you try it with Date.now() for example, it will generate once on the initial load, and then reuse it for all subsequent loads. I need something that will rerun on each navigation.

Comment: You could write the value to a store and update it [`onNavigate`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-navigation-onnavigate).